# Return every value in spreadsheet to web app table

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I'm trying to do:

1. Get every value from a spreadsheet (6 columns, ~10+ rows)

   - I can get the values. I will probably get each column individually with `.getRange(row, column, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();`. Or I could get every single value with `.getDataRange().getValues()` and then put them in the table that way?
   - **Or** would it be better to just use a for loop? -- **example at very bottom**
2. Return those values [as Templated HTML?] surrounded by `<table>, <tr>, <th>, <td>` code -- **example below**
3. Display the table with the values on a web app when a name gets
   clicked

   - Can the inserted `<table>` code start as `style="display: none;"`, and then when the name gets clicked, have the table show? Or have it in a div that is invisible then visible once clicked?

**Example of table:**

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>header1</th>
  <th>header2</th>
  <th>header3</th>
  <th>header4</th>
  <th>header5</th>
  <th>header6</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>value1</td>
  <td>value2</td>
  <td>value3</td>
  <td>value4</td>
  <td>value5</td>
  <td>value6</td>
 </tr>
 //etc
</table>
```

I dont know if what I'm trying to do counts as Templated HTML or not, or if it would be better to do this using Templated Html...

The big thing I need help with is returning every value in a table and displaying it on the web app.

---

**Example of for loop**

If I do a for loop and return every value in a column or a row

```
column1[i]  
column2[i]  
etc
```

or

```
row1[i]  
row2[i]  
etc
```

How would I return those values as a table?

Would it be something like:

```
var x = "<tr>";
var y = row1[i];
var z = "</tr>";

return x + y + z
```

If so, how would I make a whole table out of all the row/column values?

Also, how would I style the table with css once it's fully built? I'm assuming I can still add an id to the table and style it from there.

I don't know the exact number of rows there will be in the spreadsheet, so making this dynamic would be best -- probably getting all the rows instead of columns and using a for loop for each row?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

If I wanted to add another column to the table (not in the spreadsheet), how would I go about doing that? I'm trying to add an add row button to the header row, and a delete row button on the end of every row of table data.

Also, I know that you can set the `<td>` to `<td contenteditable='true'>`... but, how would I have it where the data is only editable on a newly added row AND the table cell cant be edited once a value is submitted? -- Would I need an event listener or some trigger that sees when a value is inputted and triggers that cell to `contenteditable='false'`?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use a nested `for` loop.

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getValues();
var isHeader = true;
var html = "<table>\n";
for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
  html += "<tr>\n";
  for (var j = 0; j < range[i].length; j++) {
    if (isHeader) {
      html += "<th>" + range[i][j] + "</th>\n";
    }
    else {
      html += "<td>" + range[i][j] + "</td>\n";
    }
  }
  isHeader = false;
  html += "</tr>\n";
}
html += "</table>";
```

Comment: Thank you! I have another question though - I'm adding it to the end of the original post.